# ld cannot find library that is installed

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, shared-libraries, ld

I'm sitting on an OpenSuse 11.1 x64 Box and I have a module that uses sigc++. When linking like this:

```
g++ [a lot of o's, L's and l's] -lsigc-2.0
```

I get

```
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.3/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lsigc-2.0
```

However the library is there.
In the filesystem:

```
$ sudo find / -name "libsigc-2.0*"
/usr/lib64/libsigc-2.0.so.0.0.0
/usr/lib64/libsigc-2.0.so.0
/usr/lib64/libsigc-2.0.so
```

In ld.so.conf I have:

```
/usr/lib64
```

And when invoking ldconfig:

```
$ ldconfig -v | grep sigc
libsigc-2.0.so.0 -> libsigc-2.0.so.0.0.0
```

Why?

Comment: I just realized that ldconfig doesn't put out libsigc-2.0.so but only libsigc-2.0.so.0. Both are symlinks to libsigc-2.0.so.0.0.0 but why does only the .0 link get processed by ldconfig?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm so dumb. It's an old codebase and just before the -lsigc-2.0 statement I had a

```
-Wl,-Bstatic
```

Obviously, there are no static librarys for libsigc (anymore).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that libsigc-2.0.so was linked with an [SONAME](http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/Library-related_Commands_and_Files#soname) other than `libsigc-2.0`.

> objdump -p /usr/lib64/libsigc-2.0.so | grep SONAME

If you see something unexpected, e.g. `libsigc`, you may need to create an additional symlink with that name.

Comment: It gives me  
    SONAME libsigc-2.0.so.0
and that is what ldconfig takes to set the link to libsigc-2.0.so.0.0.0